# Do these spell-like abilities, from the prestige class Holy Vindicator, provoke opportunity attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, opportunity-attack, prestige-class, critical-hit, melee-combat

The prestige class Holy Vindicator (in the Advanced Player's Guide) has three spell like abilities.

Divine Wrath and Divine Retribution (which can be triggered by a done or received critical hit) and Divine Judgement (which can be triggered by bringing a creature to -1 or less hit points with a melee attack)

Do all of these abilities provoke an opportunity attack (assuming that the attacked creature is in the conditions to strike one) since they're all spell-like abilities?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### These abilities do not provoke

First, note that all three abilities you reference, being [Spell-like abilities](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Spell-Like-Abilities-Sp-), function similarly to spells (emphasis mine):

> A spell-like ability has a casting time of 1 standard action unless noted otherwise in the ability or spell description. **In all other ways, a spell-like ability functions just like a spell.**

Further, all three abilities are used as an Immediate Action. Immediate Actions are said to behave similarly to swift actions:

> An immediate action is very similar to a swift action, but can be performed at any time—even if it’s not your turn.

Finally,  spells cast as [swift actions](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Swift-Actions) do not provoke attacks of opportunity:

> Casting a spell as a swift action doesn’t incur an attack of opportunity.

Therefore, the three quoted abilities, being Immediate Spell-like abilities should not provoke attacks of opportunity.

If you need further evidence that spells cast as an Immediate Action do not provoke attacks of opportunity, look at the [Table-Actions-in-Combat](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#Table-Actions-in-Combat) which includes an entry for the Immediate Action casting of Feather Fall stating that it does not provoke.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/Combat/#Table-Actions-in-Combat

Yes they do according to the page above, look at the table of actions in combat.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for taking the time to help others! This is the kind of answer we like here: answers the question, and backs that answer up with evidence. Unfortunately, in this case, there was additional evidence you didn’t consider (see Sdjz’s answer), that makes this answer inaccurate. Your answer may therefore draw downvotes, since an inaccurate answer is often considered “unhelpful” per the description of when users should downvote. Hopefully, that would just be a small blip on an enjoyable time here!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. In addition to what KRyan said, we also prefer to avoid link-only answers; they become useless if the linked content moves, changes, or is deleted. You should quote/summarize any relevant information from the linked page in your answer.